# A weird prototype loading thing with Yabble.js

Tags: javascript, require

I have a very odd problem that I have to assume is because of Yabble.js. I have never used Yabble.js before, and the only reason I am now is because it is a dependency of a library I'm using (Gamejs), but I would love to understand why this happens, and whether it is actually Yabble.js's fault, or possibly Gamejs's.

Here's a heavily compressed (and modified for genericness) version of my main.js:

```
var gamejs = require('gamejs');
...
function Character(/*lots of arguments*/) {
    Character.superConstructor.apply(this, arguments);
    this.somethingtomakeitaprototypeforthisexample = oneofthearguments;
}
gamejs.utils.objects.extend(Character, gamejs.sprite.Sprite);
Character.prototype.draw = function(display){
    display.blit(this.animator.image, this.pos); 
}
... /*Skipping most of the file, irrelevant to the problem*/

function main() {
    maincharacter = new Character(/* appropriate number and types of arguments */);
    ... /*skipping the rest*/
}

gamejs.ready(main);
```

I have done enough debugging to know that it gets into the `main` function no problem and that the break occurs at the call to `Character`. Here is the error message (from Chrome's console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
  main
  _readyResources
```

I have determined that `Character` is the undefined function. However, if I define my ready function thusly:

```
gamejs.ready(function(){
    console.log('Character:');
    console.log(Character);
    main(); 
});
```

the full contents of `Character`, as properly defined, prints out, but I still get the error in `main`. Thus, I know that `Character` is defined by the namespace before `main` is called.

Fun fact though: I do have a workaround. If I change the function prototype for `main` to:

```
function main(CharacterClass) {...};
```

then change the ready function to:

```
gamejs.ready(function(){ main(Character);  });
```

and change the relevant line in `main` to:

var character = new CharacterClass(...);

it works fine. But this feels really hackish.

So my question is not how to make it work, since I have that already, but rather why it is a problem and how to make it work *like it's supposed to*.

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you ever get this to work? If you can make a small test-case for my to try I could help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I ended up giving up and moved on to something else, specifically CraftyJS.